# Что определять как объекты?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача: сделать интернет-магазин, в нём есть каталог товаров и статьи новостей, собираюсь наследовать каталог от новостей, что определять как объекты? Все новости или каждую? Или как-то ещё?

Вопрос №2: количество разделов-подразделов (т.е. многоуровневость) думаю делать неограничиваемым через таблицу соответствий в базе: `раздел-его_верхний_уровень`, ещё есть какой-либо вариант, хранимый в базе?

Поправлено: наличие админки само собой, так что прошу способы с учётом её..

Comment: по второму вопросу, еще варианты по-любому есть, но этот - оптимальный, можно например в поле хранить путь по которому находится каталог, путь формировать из идентификаторов подразделов, но это больше к извращенству..

Comment: Спасибо, сомневался, но db-разраб на работе просто советовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две таблицы первая - папки (разделы, древовидная структура) вторая элементы с привязкой к папке. Вот элементы можно смело наследовать от новостей. Хлопотней создание, зато более гибкая система и использовать удобней.

Comment: а где тогда связи папок размещать?

Comment: в первой таблице я же написал, у каждой папки указываем родителя.

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе та же таблица соответствий

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на вопрос №2:**

Есть метод **nested sets** - сложный, но практичный. Также есть метод **parent id** - простой и легкий способ реализовать древовидную структуру с помощью рекурсивной функции.

Информацию по этим методам ищите в ПС.

Comment: Берем вариант с parent_id, делаем кэш результата, обновляем кэш, допустим, раз в 1 час, быстро и сердито.

Естественно это подходит, например, для меню, но не для часто изменяющейся древовидной структуры, тогда действительно лучше использовать nested sets, но сразу говорю - для неопытного программиста это жесть.

Comment: > но сразу говорю - для неопытного программиста это жесть

Никаких возражений поэтому поводу - сам пробовал ничего не понял.

Comment: @exec - я то делал пару раз, но приятных эмоций при этом не испытывал...

Comment: С рекурсией проблем нет..как бы..правда в пхп ещё не пробовал

Comment: @Sleepless - как-бы в случае с parent_id она еще как есть. И какое отношение это имеет к nested sets? Nested sets не подразумевает использование рекурсии, ее там нет и быть не может

Comment: так я про parent_id и говорю)

Comment: Речь о производительности, а код - элементарный..

Вообще для подобных целей идеально подходят документо ориентированные базы данных, типа couch, mongo. Там тупо вытягиваешь сразу все дерево и выводишь =)

Comment: Можно еще на materialized path посмотреть. Изменений дерева, я так понимаю, предполагается относительно мало и редко, а в реализации тривиальнее.